# Flutter - How to Store Long Value in Correct Format on Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, textformat

I want to store my value in cloud firestore something like this:

> ```
> // ¤ \\
>
>                    \\ ¤ //
>
>                      \\//
>
>                     (___)                    
>
>                     (___)
>
>                     (___)
>
>   \_____/\__/     \__/ \_____/
>
>     \ _ ​[     ​. * ԀѧνıԀ ​*     ]​ _ /
>
>             \_ *    ňν×   * _/
>
>                . \ __°__ /.
>
>                    |\_°_/|
>
>                     [|\_/|]
>
>                     [|[¤]|]
>
>                     [|;¤;|]
>
>                     [;;¤;;]
>
>                    ;;;;¤]|]\
>
>                   ;;;;;¤]|]-\
>
>                  ;;;;;[¤]|]--\
>
>                 ;;;;;|[¤]|]---\
>
>                ;;;;;[|[¤]|]|---|
>
>               ;;;;;[|[¤]|]|---|
>
>               ;;;;[|[¤]|/---/
>
>               ;;;[|[¤]/---/
>
>               ;;[|[¤/---/
>
>                 ;[|[/---/
>
>                 [|/---/
>
>                 /---/
>
>                /---/|]
>
>              /---/]|];
>
>            /---/¤]|]
>
>           |---|[¤]|];;;
>
>           |---|[¤]|];;;;
>
>            \--|[¤]|];;;;     
>
>              \-|[¤]|];;;;
>
>                \|[¤]|];;;
>
>                  \\¤//
>
>                    \|/
> ```

I am creating a Stylish Facebook Bio app.. but bio is mixed up when I store it in cloud firestore ): .. some correct [example](https://www.technicalzubair.com/2021/01/best-facebook-stylish-bio-2020-color.html)
I also try Firebase Real-Time Database and [Airtable](https://airtable.com/) but the same problem so where I store my bio?

example [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duy.asciiart) same like me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should convert your text into the base64 encoded form and store encoded text into cloud firestore.

Before showing text into your app please decode your encoded text.

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  var str = "Hello world";
  var bytes = utf8.encode(str);
  var base64encodeString = base64.encode(bytes);
  var base64decodeString = base64.decode('Decoed Encoded Value');
  print(base64encodeString);
  print(base64decodeString);
}
```

Comment: Ok..i will try.